# Como retornar variable en nodejs en una función para obtener respuesta de un web service

Tags: javascript, nodejs, webservice, soap, variables-globales

Tengo esta función para obtener respuesta de un web service y se ejecuta bien devuelve el valor si lo imprimo en consola. Pero yo lo necesito en una variable. Alguien podría decirme como puedo regresar la variable body, o en su defecto como puedo tener acceso a ella.

```
var http = require('follow-redirects').http;
var fs = require('fs');

function main (params)
{
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'hostname': 'localhost',
  'port': 80,
  'path': '/Bot?',
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
    'User-Agent': 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/12.0.1)',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
    'Host': 'localhost:80',
    'Content-Length': '443',    
  },
  'maxRedirects': 20
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function (chunk) {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString()); //Si lo dejo así lo muestra en pantalla pero quiero devolver este valor en una variable
  });

  res.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
});

var postData =  "Aqui va el xml";

req.write(postData);

req.end();
return body; //Esta parte es la que quiero hacer regresar el body
}
```

Gracias por su atención.

Comment: Ya lo estas haciendo con `var body` no?

Comment: o sea si se guarda en body, pero desde afuera de la función quiero acceder a body

Comment: Hace falta un poco más de contexto, ¿eso que muestras es un módulo de NodeJS? ¿Qué versión de NodeJS usas? (esto lo pregunto porque estás declarando variables con la sentencia `var`, ¿no puedes usar `let` y `const`?) Por último, ¿entiendes que el método `http.request` es asíncrono? esto significa que la respuesta sólo podrás manejarla dentro de la función `callback`. Si deseas exportar la respuesta tendrás que hacerlo de otra forma, pero para poder ayudarte necesito más información, porque tal como está lo veo incompleto. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es una variable global si necesitas acceder fuera de `res.on`. Así que sólo debes hacer algo así

```
var http = require('follow-redirects').http;
var fs = require('fs');

function main (params)
{
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'hostname': 'localhost',
  'port': 80,
  'path': '/Bot?',
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
    'User-Agent': 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/12.0.1)',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
    'Host': 'localhost:80',
    'Content-Length': '443',    
  },
  'maxRedirects': 20
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
var chunks = [];
var body = ''

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function (chunk) {
    body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString()); //Si lo dejo así lo muestra en pantalla pero quiero devolver este valor en una variable
  });

  res.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
});

var postData =  "Aqui va el xml";

req.write(postData);

req.end();
return body; //Esta parte es la que quiero hacer regresar el body
}
```

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas :)

Comment: Ya intente poner así la variable body, pero como debería acceder desde afuera, es decir como haría lo siguiente:
return req.res.on.body;
Es un ejemplo no se si sea correcto esto.

Comment: Si quieres enviarla al front seria un res.send(body), no se si te refieres a eso